# Merge changeset documents in a query

Tags: mongodb

I have recorded changes from an information system in a mongo database. Every time a set of values are set or changed, a record is saved in the mongo database.

The change collection is in the following form:

```
{ "user_id": 1, "timestamp": { "date" : "2010-09-22 09:28:02", "timezone_type" : 3, "timezone" : "Europe/Paris" } }, "changes: { "fieldA": "valueA", "fieldB": "valueB", "fieldC": "valueC" } }
{ "user_id": 1, "timestamp": { "date" : "2010-09-24 19:01:52", "timezone_type" : 3, "timezone" : "Europe/Paris" } }, "changes: { "fieldA": "new_valueA", "fieldB": null, "fieldD": "valueD" } }
{ "user_id": 1, "timestamp": { "date" : "2010-10-01 11:11:02", "timezone_type" : 3, "timezone" : "Europe/Paris" } }, "changes: { "fieldD": "new_valueD" } }
```

Of course there are thousands of records per user with different attributes which represent millions of records. What I want to do is to see a user status at a given time. By example, the user_id 1 at 2010-09-30 would be

```
fieldA: new_valueA
fieldC: valueC
fieldD: valueD
```

This means I need to flatten all the changes prior to a given date for a given user into a single record. Can I do that directly in mongo ?

**Edit**: I am using the 2.0 version of mongodb hence cannot benefit from the aggregation framework.

**Edit**: It sounds I have found the answer to my question.

```
var mapTimeAndChangesByUserId = function() { 
    var key = this.user_id;
    var value = { timestamp: this.timestamp.date, changes: this.changes };
    emit(key, value);
}

var reduceMergeChanges = function(user_id, changeset) {
    var mergeFunction = function(a, b) { for (var attr in b) a[attr] = b[attr]; };
    var result = {};

    changeset.forEach(function(e) { mergeFunction(result, e.changes); }); 

    return { timestamp: changeset.pop().timestamp, changes: result };
}
```

The reduce function merges the changes in the order they come and returns the result.

```
db.user_change.mapReduce(
    mapTimeAndChangesByUserId, 
    reduceMergeChanges,
    { 
        out:   { inline: 1 },
        query: { user_id: 1, "timestamp.date": { $lt: "2010-09-30" } },
        sort:  { "timestamp.date": 1 }
    });
'results' : [
    "_id": 1,
    "value": {
        "timestamp": "2010-09-24 19:01:52",
        "changes": {
            "fieldA": "new_valueA",
            "fieldB": null,
            "fieldC": "valueC",
            "fieldD": "valueD"
        }
    }
]
```

Which is fine to me.

Comment: You could use the aggregation framework using $group on the fields you need, or you can project them out to the top level document and $unwind then and then $addToSet them to a single document to create your single return document, however, this is provided there isn't a huge (maybe a million?) changes before that date, if there is then pre-aggregation of the sums might be a better route

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am unfortunately using the 2.0 version of mongodb and it appears the aggregation framework is available only for versions >= 2.2. I have updated the question with that remark.

Comment: I am tempted to say map reduce here, I don't think the old distinct and group functions of MongoDB can work in this way, that is if you can't do pre-aggregation

Comment: I am snorkling in the map reduce documentation right now but I am more at ease with relationnal databases. Document oriented databases are a different way of thinking I am struggling with...
I saw there is a `merge()` method that can merge two bson documents but still cannot find a way to make it to work.

Comment: A merge method? Hmm I think that might be specific to the driver rather than the server there, there is of course no server side method to merge documents, unless you mean the map reduce output of `merge`. Map reduce is quite a simple task really, it is basically just a JavaScript procedure that takes your documents, emits some values and then groups them, I would put some example code but I am a bit multitasking atm.

Comment: You are right. It belongs to the C# API. Thank you for your comments and your time, it already helped me. I am trying to figure out what javascript procedure to write.

Comment: poop too late, you learned MR, oh well :P

Answer (score 1):

You could write a MR to do this.

Since the fields are a lot like tags you can modify a nice cookbook example of counting tags here: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/count_tags/ of course instead of counting you want the latest value applied (assumption since this is not clear in your question) for that field.

So lets get our map function:

```
map = function() {
    if (!this.changes) {
        // If there were not changes for some reason lets bail this record
        return;
    }

    // We iterate the changes
    for (index in this.changes) {
        emit(index /* We emit the field name */, this.changes[index] /* We emit the field value */);
    }
}
```

And now for our reduce:

```
reduce = function(values){
    // This part is dependant upon your input query. If you add a sort of 
    // date (ts) DESC then you will prolly want the first index (0) not the last as
    // gathered here by values.length
    return values[values.length];
}
```

And this will output a single document per field change of the type:

```
{
    _id: your_field_ie_fieldA,
    value: whoop
}
```

You can then iterate the end of the (most likely) in line output and, bam, you have your changes.

This is of course one way of dong it and is not designed to be run completely in line to your app, however that all depends on the size of the data your working on; it could be run very close.

I am unsure whether the `group` and `distinct` can run on this but it looks like it might: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/#db-collection-group however I should note that group is basically a MR wrapper but you could do something like (untested just like the MR above):

```
db.col.group( {
                   key: { 'changes.fieldA': 1, // the rest of the fields },
                   cond: { 'timestamp.date': { $gt: new Date( '01/01/2012' ) } },
                   reduce: function ( curr, result ) { },
                   initial: { }
                } )
```

But it does require you to define the keys instead of just iterating them programmably (maybe a better way).